# Can we use Arduino ADK to build a custom mobile charger for Android?

Tags: android, mobile, arduino, usb, android-open-accessory

I planning on building a Custom mobile charger using Arduino ADK with Android Open Accessory protocol. My plan is to use the custom charger as a coupled device used with an Android mobile. Only that can be used to charge the mobile. If any other charger try to charge the mobile an app installed in that mobile considers this an event of theft and provides alert. I'm going to put an IC within charger which can send and receive signal to mobile over USB cable.
My android app uses `USB ACCESSORY` mode to detect and communicate with the custom charger.
I'm not familiar with hardware designing. So I'm asking stackoverflow community can this be done?
If yes provide me references. Thanks in advance.
`Note : the custom device must charge the mobile phone`.

Comment: Why don't you have a look at USB Battery Charging 1.2 (BC1.2) specification

Comment: A device is only allowed to draw upto 500mA in USB High Speed and 900mA in USB Super Speed if data communication is involved. It's termed as Standard Downstream Port(SDP).

Answer (score 0):

The accessory device can charge the android mobile phone.
To control the electric current according to different device.

Hope this can help you.
1.[How usb charging works](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/115251-how-usb-charging-works-or-how-to-avoid-blowing-up-your-smartphone)
2[.Choose the Right Charger and Power Your Gadgets Properly](http://www.wired.com/2013/12/charging-devices-faq/)

Comment: Posting relevant information here itself is a good practice, link may change later.